# Error at removing column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've received an error after trying to remove a column from my dataframe.
KeyError: "['column name'] not found in axis"
Advice is to put axis=1, but I did that and I still receive the same error.
I don't know, what the problem is.

```
  
for i in range(1,len(file_list)):
    data = pd.read_table(file_list[i], encoding='unicode_escape')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df], axis = 1)

main_dataframe = main_dataframe.drop('column name',axis=1)
```

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong here that are not directly related to your question but might be helpful: (1) Python starts indexing at 0 not 1, so your code will not be reading the first file. (2) You can just iterate through the file list `for file_name in file_list:` (3) calling `pd.concat` in a loop is inefficient, try appending all dataframes to a list first after reading and then calling `pd.concat` once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

"column name" is a placeholder for your actual column name.
For example, if you want to delete a column named "Surname", use:

```
df = df.drop("Surname",axis=1)
```

The error you have here is clearly stating that there is no column named "column name" in your dataframe.

Comment: I was aware of that ^^
But thank you. I figuered it out, something else was wrong...